# Lightning-input-field Height

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to increase the displayed height of a long text field.  I created a styleclass with height: 200px; and have tried to apply it to several of the tags in my code. No matter what I have tried I can't get the actual text in the field to expand so that the user can view several lines.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! thanks!

```
 <!--Additional Comments Section-->
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-left OpportunityDetail" > 
                <div class="slds-col QuotingStyle">   
                <hr style="display: block;margin:0mm;border-top:1mm solid #00468b"></hr>        
              
                <div class="slds-size--1-of-1">
                  <label for="amid" class="instructionheader2">Additional Comments - (use this space for 
                    general comments, Vision Product Info, Voluntary Product Info, and correct Account Name, Phone and 
                    address if you could not find the account and are attaching this
                    opportunity to your brokerage firms account)
                  </label>
                 <lightning-input-field field-name="Sales_Comments__c" id="scom" class="AddComments" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>  
              </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been several months since this was asked, but I came across this with a similar issue and was able to solve it, so I wanted to share.

When using a 'lightning-input-field', you can use a Styling hook to modify the minimum height of the LWC component. Try this in your CSS:

`:host { --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height: 200px; }`

More information on Styling Hooks can be found here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/